# ssdt msbuild parameter overriding default value

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to pass a parameter value from a Team Foundation Built into a SQL script in a SSDT Project.
I have added a parameter to the Project: $(PublishVersion)
When using it in a SQL script I get the resulting value $(SqlCmdVar__1) in the script created..

Sqlproj file:
...
    
      
        $(SqlCmdVar__1)

MSBuild Arguments (two different attempts):

```
/p:MSBuildMultiProc=false /t:Build /t:Publish /p:PublishVersion=123

/p:MSBuildMultiProc=false /t:Build /t:Publish /p:SqlCmdVar__1=456
```

EDIT: I got it working by editing the xaml and then using XmlPoke. I can post more details if there is interest.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this and currently the only supported way to load SQLCMD variables during publish is to save them in the publish profile file (.publish.xml). On the team foundation build server use the /p:[SqlPublishProfilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.tools.schema.tasks.sql.sqlpublishtask.sqlpublishprofilepath%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) parameter to specify the path to the relevant profile.

Alternatively if you use the [Deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.tools.schema.tasks.sql.sqldeploytask%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) task you should be able to specify SQLCMD variables using the /p:SqlCmdVariable=123 property (I believe this should work but needs verification). The downside is you need to specify extra properties that the publish task wouldn't require, such as connection string. Note that you can see how each task is set up by examining the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets file in the MSBuild folder. That is what defines the properties passed into each task.

Finally, most other variables in a publish profile are overridable via the command line, so supporting this for SQLCMD varibles is a legitimate request. I'd suggest creating a connect bug for this issue at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and use the category "Developer Tools(SSDT, BIDS, etc.)". That'll at least get it on the product team's radar.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not familiar with Deploy task, will look into that. But I too think it should be possible to specify a value using the /p parameter..

Comment: Yes, this is an oversight in the current functionality, especially since it's supported when publishing through SqlPackage.exe. As I mentioned the best way to raise this is via the connect bug system so that you can see if the bug gets fixed, and so that it's identified as a blocking issue customers have run into.

Answer (score 1):

Lonny.Bastien (MSFT) has [provided an answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/532fd33b-1174-4485-9462-59f737db0f6b/correct-way-to-override-sqlcommandvariables-with-tfs-msbuild-values?forum=ssdt): use /t:Deploy instead of /t:Publish. This uses the built-in Deploy action of the Project itself. You must edit the Project Properties/SQLCMD Variables to use an indirect value (please see link above for example). This Task does not take a Publish configuration, so you will have to provide all arguments.  For example, SQLCMD override:

```
<ItemGroup>
<SqlCmdVariable Include="BuildId">
  <DefaultValue>
  </DefaultValue>
  <Value>$(SqlCmdVar__1)</Value>
</SqlCmdVariable>
```

...and msbuild arguments:

```
/t:Deploy /p:SqlCmdVar__1=BLDNUMBER  /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=SOMESERVER;Integrated Security=True;" /p:TargetDatabaseName=PUBLISH_DBNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

try with /Variables:PublishVersion=123

Comment: I think that might only work if you use SqlPackage.exe, rather than the publish task. It's a good suggestion though and might be easier to do than trying to use the publish task.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, bu I have already tried that and Kevin is right, it doesn't work.